# fractions changing to decimal

Tags: fractions

this is my code but when it shows up on my android display it changes my fractions to a decimal how do i keep it in this format.

```
public void readyForJavascript(final String arg) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.addSlot({ " +
                "1:1, 2: 5/16, 3: 3/8,  4:  7/16,  5:  1/2,  6:  9/16," +
                "7: 5/8, 8: 3/4, 9: 7/8, 10: 1, 11: 1/18, 12: 1/4 });");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.addSlot({ " +
                "1: 'AM', 2: 'PM'});");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.addSlot({ " +
        "1: 'AM', 2: 'PM'});");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.open();");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your fractions in single quotes:

```
"1:1, 2: '5/16', 3: '3/8' .......
```

I think at some point your Javascript sees 3/8 and evaluates it as a calculation.